# Regex to capture title from year-month-day-title.ext

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have files that have names on the form of:

```
year-month-day-title.ext
```

Year is 4 digits, Month and Day are 2 digits each.

I want to capture just the title from the file name, the titles are composed of alphanumeric characters and hyphens.

My attempt with `sed` was:

```
sed -En 's/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-([\w\\-]+)\.ext/\1/p'
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not sure why, I'm not very handy with regex/sed :(

Any standard util is fine as long as I can pipe my file names in and get my titles out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `sed` uses POSIX regex which is different from PCRE for example, so \w, \d are not even available, your regex would be something like:

```
echo '0000-00-00-title.ext' | sed -En 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(.+)\.ext/\1/p'
```

Output:

```
title
```

Answer (score 0):

I think such an issue is more suitable for awk

```
echo "year-month-day-title.ext" | awk -F"[-.]" '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other awk version

```
echo '0000-00-00-title.ext' | awk -F. '{n=split($1,a,"-");print a[n]}'
```

This works since date has fixed lengt

```
echo '0000-00-00-title.ext' | awk -F. '{print substr($1,12)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another one using `cut`:

```
echo 0000-00-00-title.ext | cut -d- -f3 | cut -d. -f1
```